# How to track device IDs assignments in Windows?

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse, sleep, hibernate, event-log

Is there a way to keep track of device IDs as they're assigned by the OS? I'm using Windows 8.1, trying to track mouse IDs in specific. A cursory glance at the System logs turned nothing useful.

To elaborate a little, I'm having issues with my mouse and Wacom tablet, which when it comes to Windows device IDs is also considered a mouse. Both devices stop working after a few Sleep/Hibernate cycles, and I suspect it's due Window's limitation regarding this kind of device: It can only assign 20 of them.

Because both devices are connected to a display that power downs upon hibernating, Windows might be assigning them new IDs upon each wake up until it runs out. There are other clues that suggest this guess is correct, but nothing concrete.

I'd like to track these IDs to confirm this is the cause before going around changing my setup to a less ideal one trying to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Microsoft article
[Hardware ID](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/hardware-ids):

> To find the list of hardware IDs for a given device, follow these
> steps:
>
> 1. Open Device Manager.
> 2. Find the device in the tree.
> 3. Right-click the device and select **Properties**.
> 4. Select the Details tab.
> 5. In the **Property** drop-down, select **Hardware Ids** or **Compatible Ids**.

You device should be in the Device Manager tree under
"Mice and other pointing devices".

If you wish to track changes, you could use
[devcon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon):

> DevCon (Devcon.exe), the Device Console, is a command-line tool that displays detailed information about devices on computers running Windows. You can use DevCon to enable, disable, install, configure, and remove devices.

The command to use is
[DevCon HwIDs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-hwids)
that displays the hardware IDs, compatible IDs, and device instance IDs of the specified devices.

Its syntax is:

```
devcon hwids {* | ID [ID ...] | =class [ID [ID ...]]}
```

where ID Specifies one or more devices by using an hardware ID
or part of a hardware ID.
This way, if there is a common part to all the IDs that are assigned
to the devices, you could query on this part.

If you wish to call devcon from a batch file and append its answer
to a text file, execute it immediately after wake.

See the article
[Run Program When Windows Resumes from Sleep or Hibernate](https://sumtips.com/how-to/run-program-windows-wakes-up-sleep-hibernate/).

Comment: Yeah... thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't help in *tracking changes*. Worst case scenario it'll help in manually writing down every ID after waking the computer, I guess.

Comment: OK, added. Some small amount of work is required on your part.

Comment: It's no problem at all! I'd rather put a little effort in automating a log generator than try to rely on remembering to check IDs every time, because I couldn't reliably trigger the issue yet (it's not as easy as 10/20 sleeps -> mouse dies). Some times it takes way to long to happen. Thanks!

Comment: You can enable the auditing of PnP. The security event log can then be checked. Probably will have your device of interest.